# Deploying and running .Net Core API to an FTP Server

Tags: c#, deployment, ftp, .net-core

i am developing a .Net Core Web Application (.Net Core) and have an FTP Server from a hoster. I think its a Linux Server.

I used the "publish" function of VS and deployed a newly created .Net Core App to the FTP Server.

The files are there but i think the App is not running. If i click "Run" in VS it opens a website with "[value1, value2]". If i navigate to my FTP Url there is no response. In my understanding i should get the same response than when starting the API via VS.

How do i start or deployCorrectly a .Net Core API to a FTP Server?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need IIS or other server that supports .net core.
The problem is that FTP is just like file storage.
You can contact me if you need help with it.